# Disable schema registry in StreamBridge

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

im trying to configure my spring application to use kafka without Schema Registry.
For sending messages im using StreamBridge.
Is there any way to configure StreamBridge work without schema registry?

I have tried to set auto.schema.registry=false but it wont help.
I think i need to make my own StreamBridge bean

Comment: Kafka doesn't use Schema Registry on its own, and neither should Cloud Streams; only if you have defined serializer/deserializer for it, will it be used

Comment: Also, that property you've listed is not mentioned in the docs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_configuration_options